# Leverage browser caching on nginx

Tags: nginx

I run page speed and I am getting: 
    "Leverage browser caching"
I have added the following directive in to my nginx.conf

```
location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
expires 30d;
add_header Pragma public;
add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

but I am still getting the same message from google.

Comment: See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64257300) which might help.