# Browser caching setup for images on NGINX with proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

I am using NGINX as a reverse proxy and have the following setup that redirects all requests to my SPA container

```
location / {
    proxy_pass  http://172.x.x.x;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 404 = /index.html;
}
```

This works but all images have their expiry set to the default (`max-age=3600`).
When I add the following block that is supposed to set the expiry for all image types then none of the images work anymore (`404 NOT FOUND`).

```
location ~* \.(jpg|png)$ {
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    expires 1M;
}
```

I tried nesting this block inside the first one but then I also get the `404` responses.

Why doesn't this work and what should I change so that all images have an extended `max-age`?

Comment: Your new `location` is missing a `proxy_pass  http://172.x.x.x;` statement.

Comment: Yep, that was it. If you post your comment as an answer then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx chooses one `location` to [process a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html). It uses the directives within the location block or inherited from the surrounding block.

If the requests for `.jpg` and `.png` URIs are to be passed upstream, the `location` also needs to contain a `proxy_pass` statement.

---

Alternatively, use a `map` to set the `expires` value. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires) for details.

For example:

```
map $request_uri $expires {
    default             off;
    ~*\.(jpg|png)(\?|$) 1M;
}    
server {
    ...
    expires $expires;

    location / {
        ...
    }
}
```

I think that `expires` already sets the cache-control header, but you can also use another `map` to set the value of an `add_header` directive.